# which classes are Rails cacheable

Tags: ruby, class, caching, types, ruby-on-rails-5

My class caches fine on development environment, but can I be sure about production environment, with memcache, redis, or whatever running? I wonder which data types are cacheable with low level `Rails.cache.write('mykey', myobj)` besides strings, numbers and their array? Are there some criterion to see is a given class save to cache? At the least with the typical cache stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: [**ANY** object](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching).

Longer answer: By default, [objects over 1Kb will be compressed](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5aaaa1630ae9a71b3c3ecc4dc46074d678c08d67/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L155). And by default, the compression is done via [`Marshal.dump`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5aaaa1630ae9a71b3c3ecc4dc46074d678c08d67/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L848).

[The documentation for `Marshal.dump` states](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Marshal.html#method-c-dump):

> Marshal can't dump following objects:
>
> - anonymous Class/Module.
> - objects which are related to system (ex: Dir, File::Stat, IO, File,
>   Socket and so on)
> - an instance of MatchData, Data, Method, UnboundMethod, Proc, Thread,
>   ThreadGroup, Continuation
> - objects which define singleton methods

So in order to cache large objects that fall under the above categories, you'd need to either increase the `compress_threshold`, set `compress: false` or define an alternate way of "compressing" the data (?!).

Comment: I imagine the backend store e.g. MemCache might have it is own limits, probably not addressed by Rails. Something like "key used is a string with a maximum length of 250 bytes. The value has a 1 megabyte size limit..." Keys though seems be handled by rails https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-keys

Comment: *"The value has a 1 megabyte size limit"* -- That's a fair point; there's inevitably going to be *some* size limit, depending on the back-end store and other hardware limitations. However, the question was strictly asking *which classes* are cacheable.